# How to dump classifier and parameters into a table?

Tags: python, mysql, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to dump the classifier and its parameters into a table as such:

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn import datasets

iris = datasets.load_iris()
X, y = iris.data, iris.target
clf = DecisionTreeClassifier().fit(X, y)
```

When I print `clf` I get the following:

```
DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight=None, criterion='gini', max_depth=None,
            max_features=None, max_leaf_nodes=None,
            min_impurity_split=1e-07, min_samples_leaf=1,
            min_samples_split=2, min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0,
            presort=False, random_state=None, splitter='best')
```

How can I dump this into a `.txt` or even better into a table that contains this info under columns. For example, under the `Algorithm Name` column it would say `C4.5` etc...

I tried using `from sklearn.externals import joblib` and did: `joblib.dump(clf, "outputfile.txt")`. I would get messed up text or non-ASCII characters.

Ideal output: [image: table]

I understand this maybe a far fetch but my question is just how to output the classifier properly and capture all of the required info.

Comment: I have not worked with scikit learn much, but I would say that `joblib.dump` is not profer tool for what you want to do. [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html) says this is a replacement of "pickle".

Comment: @Leonard2 well `pickle` is used to save classifiers and their parameters and then load them to win time and cost, `joblib` is same I understand but I thought I might get it to do something else that `pickle` couldn't.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to load the object/ model as it was then `joblib` is the way (or pickle but scikit suggests joblib).
If you want to keep the parameters and use them:

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
import json

dt = DecisionTreeClassifier()
# do your stuff 
# ... 
# you can dump the parameters to json or to any other type of storage, load them and re use them.
with open("somefile.json", "wb") as f:
    json.dump(dt.get_params(), f)

# ... 
# and load them...with some proper error handling...
with open("somefile.json") as f:
    dt.set_params(**json.load(f))
```

In general, for what you are asking for, you'll have to do something custom. ( I too am in the process of implementing something to hold the information in a database in order to be able to re-use it but I have not found a workaround for joblib yet)

Comment: I'll try what you mentioned as see what comes out of it. Thanks! Also, since we generally are aim for the same thing maybe we can share our findings

Comment: @MichaelMMeskhi Let me know if this works for you and if you find another way! I will let you know how my quest goes. For the time being I've gotten [this far](https://bitbucket.org/mkaranasou/replicable_experiments)